# Passing a large text to bash curl url

Tags: bash, curl

I'm crawling the json results from a web api that takes text as input. Example:

```
curl http://www.example.com/annotate?text=${long_text}&input_format=html&output=json
```

I get the error of list of arguments is too long. Then I changed to:

```
curl -d "text=${long_text}&input_format=html&output=json" http://www.example.com/annotate?
```

I still get the same error. I read the ${long_text} from an html file since the api doesn't accept file as parameter. Any suggestions to overcome this error?

Comment: BTW, if you want the contents of your HTML file to be urlencoded, you could just use `--data-urlencode text@htmlfile -d input_format=html -d output=json`.

Comment: is it `--data-urlencode text=text@htmlfile` ?

Comment: No; it's specified in the man page precisely as I described above.

Comment: ...btw, `-d` doesn't do the same thing as passing an argument as a query parameter. You might *need* the different thing it does, since web servers aren't required to accept query parameters beyond a certain length, but be sure that the remote webapp actually accepts the parameters you're passing as POST data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The limit on command-line length is enforced by the operating system -- it's not anything bash can do anything about. (It's actually not just command-line length, but combined size of the command line and all exported environment variables).

---

You can tell `curl` to read data from a file as a workaround:

```
# create a temporary file, and arrange for it to be deleted on exit
tempfile=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/curldata.XXXXXX")
trap 'rm -rf "$tempfile"' 0 ERR

# put the data you want to POST in that file
# this doesn't have the same error because printf is a bash builtin
printf '%s' "text=${long_text}&input_format=html&output=json" >"$tempfile"

# ...and pass the filename, prefixed with an @, to curl
curl --data "@$tempfile" http://example.com/annotate
```

---

If you don't want to bother with managing a temporary file, you can read from stdin:

```
curl --data "@-" http://example.com/annotate \
  <<<"text=${long_text}&input_format=html&output=json"
```

---

Alternately, if you need your input file to be urlencoded, you can tell `curl` to do that for you, and have it read from said file itself:

```
curl --data-urlencode text@htmlfile -d input_format=html -d output=json \
  http://example.com/annotate
```

Comment: `-data-urlencode text@htmlfile -d input_format=html -d output=json` solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. Moving that from my comment on the question into the answer proper.

Answer (score -2):

```
curl -d "text=`cat long_text_file`&input...."  http://www.yay.com
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The size of the generated argv array is still the same as it was before.

Comment: BTW, if you click the code-formatting button, your selected text will be indented by four spaces, such that it'll be treated as code, so you won't need to worry about your backticks being interpreted as markdown syntax. Or, of course, you can just indent your lines yourself.

Comment: As @CharlesDuffy pointed out it is another way to approach the problem but it doesn't solve it. I tried it before. still `/usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long`