# Passing a long JSON text to curl POST

Tags: linux, curl

I am referring to the thread: [Passing a large text to bash curl url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887130/passing-a-large-text-to-bash-curl-url)

I have a shell script that looks like:

```
#!bin/bash
curl --location --request POST 'example.com/abcxyz' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: my_secret_key' \
--data-raw '{_my_very_long_json_content_here}'
```

Approach 1: I put everything after the `curl`, i.e. from  `--location ...` to the end to a test.txt file then

```
tempfile = test.txt
curl  "@$tempfile"
```

and I get the error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.txt`

Approach 2: I put everything in a `test.sh` file:

```
#!bin/bash
curl --location --request POST 'example.com/abcxyz' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Cookie: my_secret_key' --data-raw '@-' <<< 'my_very_long_json'
```

and I have an error `{"error":"invalid character '@' looking for beginning of value","code":3}(base)`

What should I do to pass a very long JSON content to curl POST?

Note that, if the JSON content is not too long, I can put everything in a SH file then run

`bash test.sh`

and it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

`--data-raw` specifically disables `@` interpretation. Use `--data @-` or `--data-binary @-` to read from stdin.

```
curl --location --request POST 'example.com/abcxyz' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: my_secret_key' \
--data @- <<< '{_my_very_long_json_content_here}'
```

You might find a [heredoc](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/) more ergonomic than a long string:

```
curl --location --request POST 'example.com/abcxyz' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: my_secret_key' \
--data @- <<'DATA'
{
  'json': 'here'
}
DATA
```